# Adding the author photo along with the name in the title page

Tags: beamer, graphics, titles

Friends, I'm trying to add a photo along with each author name in a `beamer` title page. Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\theauthor}[1]{%
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{#1}
}%

\title{A dinner with us}
\author[Alice and Bob]{\theauthor{alice} and \theauthor{bob}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which gives me the following output:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to add the name below the photo, but I had no luck. At first, I thought about using a `tabular` environment, but I could not make it work.

I'll probably get rid of the "and" word and put both author blocks aligned, let's say:

[image: Alignment]

Any suggestion on how could I achieve this? I know this might be a very easy question, but it puzzles me. `:-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\theauthor}[3][3cm]{%
  \vbox{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}\hbox to #1{\hss#3\hss}}}

\title{A dinner with us}
\author[Alice and Bob]{\theauthor{alice}{Alice}\qquad\theauthor{bob}{Bob}}
```

Using `tabular` conflicts with the massaging done by **beamer**, whereas a more *primitive* approach is successful, in the sense of using primitive commands such as `\vbox`, `\hbox` or `\halign` that won't be untimely expanded during the processing by **beamer**. The optional argument to `\theauthor` can be used to set the width of the image (default 3cm).

Alternative definition:

```
\newcommand{\theauthor}[2]{\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
  \includegraphics[scale=.3]{#1}\cr#2\cr}}}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks egreg. `:-)`

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're okay with essentially creating a custom title page, you can use the `\columns` environment to create blocks for your authors. Modifying the `\theauthor` command to include an extra `#1` as shown will place the author name under each picture. Alternatively you can add an extra argument to the command for more flexibility.

### What it looks like

[image: An evening with emmy and george]

*The depicted people are Emmy Noether and George Stokes. I just wanted a pair of public domain photos that no one would care about me using.*

### The Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\theauthor}[1]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{#1}\\#1
}%

\title{A dinner with us}
\author{Emmy and George}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\centering
\begin{huge}An evening with us
\end{huge}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{columns}[c]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\theauthor{Emmy}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\theauthor{George}
\end{columns}

\vspace{1cm}
\today

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It's not elegant by any stretch of the imagination, but it seems to work pretty well.

References:

I used [HappyMutant's page on beamer](http://happymutant.com/latex/misce/beamer.php) as a reference for setting up columns.

Comment: Thanks Richard, it's a nice answer. `:-)`