# How to include two team member's photo in titlepage in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, slideshow

This question is an extended version of [How to align multiple author's name, roll, institute in titlepage in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414090/how-to-align-multiple-authors-name-roll-institute-in-titlepage-in-beamer). And the viewing the photo in circle is taken from [How to show circled portion of a image in beamer slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414741/how-to-show-circled-portion-of-a-image-in-beamer-slide)

I want to make a slide with two author's name, roll, and photo. I can easily add author's name, and roll, but when I include their photo the content of the slide is gone.

My trying source code is here -

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
}
\begin{document}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author{
  \parbox{2.5cm}{
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) circle (1);
\node at (0.62,-3) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}}; %<-you'll need to adjust these
% coordinates, I do not have your original picture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
\centering Md.Al-Helal\\Roll:SH-51}\hspace{1cm}
}
\parbox{2.5cm}{
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) circle (1);
\node at (0.62,-3) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}}; %<-you'll need to adjust these
% coordinates, I do not have your original picture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
{\centering Jobayed Ullah\\Roll:EK-107}}
\institute{Computer Science \& Engineering\\CSEDU}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author{Jianhua Tang\\ Wee Pen Tay\\ Tony Q. S. Quek}
\institute{IEEE Transactions on Wireless Communications, vol 14, no. 9}
\date{September 2015}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42797529#42797529

Comment: Note that the `overlayarea` create a overlay area. So it's no wonder that the contents are gone. You should have only one `overlayarea` of that size per slide.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30329/adding-the-author-photo-along-with-the-name-in-the-title-page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is combination of various problems:

- missing or misplaced parenthesis caused text outside of a frame environment. Beamer tried to rescue this situation by inserting an additional frame
- as @marmot already explained in his comment, `overlayarea` are to be used in combination with overlays
- if you mess with the author definition instead of redefining the title page template, the same definition will also be used for the authors in the footline, thus causing additional images on the bottom of the frame. You can rescue this by giving short author names, but IMHO it would be better to redefine the title page.
- your title and institute are too long for the footline, you should give a short alternative

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\title[short title]{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}

\author[author names]{%
    \parbox{2.5cm}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \clip (0,0) circle (1);
            \node at (0.62,-3) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \centering Md.Al-Helal\\Roll:SH-51
    }%
    \hspace{1cm}
    \parbox{2.5cm}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \clip (0,0) circle (1);
            \node at (0.62,-3) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \centering Jobayed Ullah\\Roll:EK-107
    }
}

\institute[short inst.]{Computer Science \& Engineering\\CSEDU}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed after 30mins of debugging (probably my mistake) I had copied the `\author` command in the preamble and not in the document body and received an error of the form `Argument of \pgfkeys@temp has an extra }.<inserted text>\parl.21 }`. Before I organised my documents such that the `\author`, `\title`,.. commands are in the preamble. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Arne If the `\author` etc. are in the preamble, they are getting used for pdf meta data. All the extra formatting instructions from this answer will probably cause a problem for this. That's why I said in my 3rd bullet point, that such an approach is not good and redefining the title page would be much more robust (with beamer v3.70 or newer you could simply redefine the author template)

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification!